# Increase upload limit on Azure Web Service / Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages app with a file upload page. I want to allow up to 60 MB uploads on that page. I can get do this locally by adding a `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="62914560" />` tag to my local `applicationhost.config` file in the `.vs` directory, but that doesn't help the deploy.

Here's what I've tried

1. Adding `[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 60 * 1024 * 1024)]` and `[RequestSizeLimit(60 * 1024 * 1024)]` to the `PageModel` for the page in question
2. Adding `services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => { options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 60 * 1024 * 1024; });` to my `Startup.cs`
3. Adding a middleware handler with `app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/mypagepath"), appBuilder => { appBuilder.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = null; });`
4. Adding a `Web.config` file to the root of the project with the `<requestLimits>` tag. If I deploy that file the whole app stops working.

Everything works locally but when I deploy to my Azure App Service, I get this error

> The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If you add `web.config` file, you don't need to add anything in your code.*

In .net core project, you also can use `web.config` file.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="62914560" /> <!--60MB-->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: This was point number 4 on the what I've tried list. When I did that it made the whole app stop working on azure app services.

Comment: @just.another.programmer Okey,  can you show your upload function, we can test it. Normally we can fix the issue by using `maxAllowedContentLength` in `web.config`.

Comment: I forgot to add the `<security>` tag when I tested this the first time, it's working now.